# What is the max size for an array of complex doubles?

Tags: c++, arrays

In C++, what is the maximum size of a one dimensional array of complex doubles (i.e. `std::complex<double> array[dimension]`)?
Is there a difference to the max size if I declare the array in main versus globally?

Comment: This depends on the stack size your software got assigned from the OS, your architecture and your RAM size. Basically std::min(stack-size, 2^architecture - 1, Ram-size)/ sizeof(std::complex<double>).

Globals and locals are both initialized on the stack. But there is a difference, if you create it as dynamic heap object.

Comment: a global array can be utterly massive. It's size  will not be bound by the limits of Automatic Storage. But a global array is also a complete free-for-all. In a complex program it gets difficult to track who is messing with global variables because EVERYBODY can. This quickly turns into a debugging nightmare. Instead use `std::vector` and keep its scope as narrow as possible.

Comment: @FabianKeßler globals don't normally go on the stack. Some reading on what goes where: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration. Worth noting the complete absence of the terms "stack" and "heap" in the linked documentation. Stacks and heaps are implementation details that C++ doesn't care about. So long as the requirements are met you can use hamster wheels and pixie dust for storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum size of the array will be `M / sizeof(std::complex<double>)` bytes where `M` is the remaining free memory in bytes. Amount of free memory is affected by how much total memory there is, and by how much memory is used for other purposes.

If you declare the array as an automatic variable, then it will have automatic storage. The amount of automatic storage is limited on most systems. Typical total automatic storage shared by all automatic variables is one or few megabytes.

Comment: The value of `M` depends on more than free memory.   On some virtual memory systems, the amount of swap available can affect the maximum possible size of an array (with a performance trade-off that acting on elements of that array can be horrendously slow, since they are represented on a slow device like a hard drive and accessing array elements potentially swap them between memory and the swap file).